# Parse request vs refresh

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm not all that new to ios but parse is fairly new. I have a question about the cost of "requests", or really how to reduce requests to reduce costs.

Ive read through the Parse documentation and have a decent understanding of the difference between fetch and refresh my question comes down to the payment of it all.

In terms of data, is it possible to check if an object exists in parse before you spend a request to query for it.

Basically, confirm object in parse exists before query, fetch (based on object id or another custom column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will check without actually downloading any objects.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"email" equalTo:emailerL];
if([query countObjects] > 0) {
   ... it exists!
}
```